Change BottomAppBar Content with navigation
I want to use the Jetpack Compose scaffold and app bars in my android app.  I want to have the scaffold content as well as the scaffolds BottomAppBar content change with navigation.  I tried to use a second NavHost for the BottomAppBar content on the same NavController but that didn't work (after the first navigation, the bottom bar would remain blank)
        Scaffold(content = { paddingValues ->
            ContentNavHost(paddingValues, navController)
            }
        , bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar (content={
                BottomBarNavHost(navController)
            }))


Obviously, I can create individual scaffolds with their own app bars, but that causes the entire app bar to re-render on every switch.
I would like to be able to use my navController in two places, or something similar.

But when you replace the content and the bottom bar, what's left in the scaffold that should not be recomposed on navigation? I don't see why you cannot just move the scaffold inside the destination you navigate to. Scaffolds can also be nested, if that helps... Can you explain why whis isn't working for you?

@Leviathan when switching between separate BottomAppBars (through nested Scaffolds) the entire bar flickers or fades in or are otherwise animated, rather than just the content being animated.  I would rather have the buttons inside the app bar be animated as in the material v3 example for it.  This might be fixable somewhere else, I'm still learning.
